# QML: ListView items expansion

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a ListView and its delagates. My intention is to make expandable delegates (eg. I have three parent delegates, if the parent delegate is clicked, it will expand its children). I made this demonstration:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    id: root
    width: 1406; height: 536

    ListModel {
        id: animalsModel
        ListElement { name: "Cats"; isExpanded: false; type: "parent"}
        ListElement { name: "Puss in Boots 1"; isExpanded: false; type: "Cats"}
        ListElement { name: "Puss in Boots 2"; isExpanded: false; type: "Cats"}
        ListElement { name: "Puss in Boots 3"; isExpanded: false; type: "Cats"}

        ListElement { name: "Dogs"; isExpanded: false; type: "parent"}
        ListElement { name: "Pug 1"; isExpanded: false; type: "Dogs" }

        ListElement { name: "Birds"; isExpanded: false; type: "parent"}
        ListElement { name: "Parrot 1"; isExpanded: false; type: "Birds" }
        ListElement { name: "Parrot 2"; isExpanded: false; type: "Birds" }
        ListElement { name: "Parrot 3"; isExpanded: false; type: "Birds" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listing

        width: 181
        height: parent.height
        model: animalsModel

        delegate: listdelegate
    }

    Component {
        id: listdelegate

        Rectangle {
            id: menuItem
            width: 181
            height: type === "parent" ? 55 : 0
            color: type === "parent" ? "lightblue" : "white"
            border.width: 1

            states: State {
                name: "expanded"
                when: isExpanded
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: menuItem
                    height: 55
                }
            }

            transitions:[
                Transition {
                    from: ""
                    to: "expanded"
                    reversible: true
                    SequentialAnimation {
                        PropertyAnimation { property: "height"; duration: 1000 }
                    }
                }
            ]

            Text {
                id: text
                text: name
                clip: true
                anchors.fill: parent
            }

            MouseArea {
                function expand(isExpanded) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < animalsModel.count; ++i) {
                        var animal = animalsModel.get(i)

                        if(animal.type === name) {
                            animal.isExpanded = isExpanded
                        }
                    }
                }

                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if (type == "parent") {
                        if (isExpanded == false) {
                            // expand
                            expand(true)
                        }
                        else {
                            // collapse
                            expand(false)
                        }

                        isExpanded = !isExpanded
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly except one small detail: the height animation is very expensive in my case (I have more complex delagate). How can I make the expanding animation height independent. My idea is to not resize the delagetes, only hide them behind the parent. Like a train going into the tunnel. But I cannot manipulate the x property of delagates in case of vertical ListView.

Any idea how to achive this? In the best scenario how to make the animation I described?

Comment: As a workaround you can hide content of expanding item during the animation and show that at the end.

Comment: When they are that complex, is it even a good idea to have them existing all the time and not just instantiate them when they shall come in existence? Another idea is, to have them not as siblings to their "parent" in the `ListView`. Instead you can filter them out, and create them in "Columns" in the `parent` delegate. This column can be expanded/closed by changing the size of the clipping parent object.

Comment: Do you plan on creating the models in QML or in C++ eventually?

Comment: check this out: https://forum.qt.io/topic/66565/qml-expandable-menu-with-subitems/2